# Include extra (ellipsis/dot dot dot) arguments within custom function

Tags: r, ellipsis, tidytext

I´m doing a project on Text Mining, and therefore I want to write a small function counting the number of distinct tokens within a text. The Tokenization is done by the function `tidytext::unnest_token` which is basically a wrapper for the usage of `tokenizers::tokenize_ngrams` with the pipe. My current approach is the following:

```
count_tokens <- function(data,output,token="words", ...){
  data %>% 
    select(textcolumn) %>% 
    tidytext::unnest_tokens(tbl=output, input=textcolumn, ...) %>% 
    n_distinct()
}
```

This works fine (even with the `...`) as long as I use arguments from `tidytext::unnest_token`, such as `to_lower` or `drop`.
`count_tokens(data, word, to_lower = FALSE)`  works fine!

Now, the documentation of `tidytext::unnest_token` states that `...` can also be used as *extra arguments passed on to tokenizers, such as `strip_punct` for "words" and "tweets", `n` and `k` for "ngrams" and "skip_ngrams", (...).* However, if I include the parameter `n` from the ellipsis argument in my function, it crashes.

`count_tokens(data, ngram, token = "ngrams", to_lower = FALSE, n = 10)` brings up the following error message:

`Error in tf(col, lowercase = to_lower, ...) : unused argument (n = 10)`

Can someone point me in the right direction or even tell me how I need to adapt my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your example seems to not be a valid one.
For me updated function works correctly.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)

count_tokens <- function(data,output,token="words", ...){
  d %>% 
    select(txt) %>% 
    tidytext::unnest_tokens(output, input="txt", token = token, ...) %>% 
    n_distinct()
}

d <- tibble(txt = prideprejudice)

count_tokens(d, "word", to_lower = FALSE)
#> [1] 6915

count_tokens(d, "ngram", token = "ngrams", to_lower = FALSE, n = 8)
#> [1] 122189

count_tokens(d, "ngram", token = "ngrams", to_lower = FALSE, n = 5)
#> [1] 121599

count_tokens(d, "ngram", token = "ngrams", to_lower = FALSE, n = 3)
#> [1] 104664
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it! Since including the token argument without n worked, I didn´t catch that the argument was actually missing within the function. Cheers!